# Error trying to update migration .NET Maui with EFcore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, maui, maui-android

In my .Net MAUI project I'm trying to change update my migration. I added a property to my model and did;

1. Add-Migration AddBlogCreatedTimestamp in the packet manager console
2. Update-Database in the packet manager console

It tells me 'build succeeded' but also give me the error "Startup project targets platform 'Android'. The Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools don't support this platform"

When I try to run the app on my android phone I get: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: t.Description'.'
Description being the property I added to the model.

When I run the app on windows it works fine.

Is there anyway around this? I read the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#other-target-frameworks) that comes with the error but that didn't help me.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) with your solution(Edited section) and accept it as an answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: After changing the name of my Dbpath in taskcontext I got it to work. Not sure how. Maybe I messed with it a while back and I changed it to the original name back now.

```
    public TaskContext()
    {
        var folder = 
        Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
        DbPath = System.IO.Path.Join(path, "Todo.db");
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
```

The DBPath was "ToDo.db" before

Answer (score 0):

- As indicated in [the link you provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#other-target-frameworks):
  you'll need to create a dummy project (using `.Net Core` or `.Net Framework`) to represent the startup project.
- The command now would be something like this:

  `Add-Migration AddBlogCreatedTimestamp -StartupProject <path-to-your-dummy-project>`

Comment: Trying that gives me "The '<' operator is reserved for future use" and without the < and > it gives me: "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Project '(ProjectName)' is not found.PM>

Comment: Did you try project name only? Like: `Add-Migration AddBlogCreatedTimestamp -StartupProject DummyProject`

Comment: Yes I did try that